# two connected comboboxes are not working

Tags: c#, wpf, if-statement, combobox

I have two comboboxes. When I change value of category combobox, it should automatically change value of size combobox.

[image]

```
private void New_Item_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'pitauzDBDataSet.Item' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
    this.itemTableAdapter.Fill(this.pitauzDBDataSet.Item);

    cbx_product_category.Items.Add("Pita");
    cbx_product_category.Items.Add("Drinks");
    cbx_product_category.Items.Add("Other Foods");
}

private void cbx_product_category_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string ItemSelected = cbx_product_category.SelectedIndex.ToString();
    if(ItemSelected == "Pita")
    {
        cbx_product_size.Items.Clear();
        cbx_product_size.Items.Add("Small");
        cbx_product_size.Items.Add("Regular");
        cbx_product_size.Items.Add("Large");
        cbx_product_size.Items.Add("Very-Large");
    }
    if(ItemSelected == "Drinks")
    {
        cbx_product_size.Items.Clear();
        cbx_product_size.Items.Add("0.5L");
        cbx_product_size.Items.Add("1L");
        cbx_product_size.Items.Add("1.5L");
    }
    if (ItemSelected == "Other Foods")
    {
        cbx_product_size.Items.Clear();
        cbx_product_size.Items.Add("Half");
        cbx_product_size.Items.Add("Full");
    }
}
```

It is not giving any error. Just logic not working.

Comment: Is the `cbx_product_category_SelectedIndexChanged` actually firing?

Comment: SelectedIndex get index not value man!

Comment: could not understand. sorry

Comment: What happens when you set a breakpoint inside the `SelectedIndexChanged` event and trace the executiion?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is in this line here

`string ItemSelected = cbx_product_category.SelectedIndex.ToString();`

`SelectedIndex` will return a number, not the item itself.

What you want to do is this:

```
var item = cbx_product_category.SelectedItem;
string ItemSelected = "";
if(item != null)
    ItemSelected = item.ToString();
```

*Note, since this is in the selection changed event SelectedItem shouldn't ever return null, but it doesn't really hurt to make sure

Comment: Coud not get. I have chaged to your version, but it is giving me error Sir

Comment: Embedded statement cannot be declaration or labelled statement----------saying so. My project is working with localDB now

Comment: @AmirsaidhonZuhirxo'jaev good catch, I had an error in my code as I was declaring the variable in the if statement when it should be declared outside